# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but I can't see where it goes out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

The full error is:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 at Taskone.main(Taskone.java:15)`

My full code is:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Taskone
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int experiments = 10;
        int[] arrayone = new int[ 14 ];
        Die die = new Die();

        for(int i=0; i<experiments ;i++) {
            int d1 = die.roll();
            int d2 = die.roll();
            int dT = d2 + d1 ;
            arrayone[dT]++; //Line which throws the exception

        }

        for(int j=0; j<arrayone.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("The amount of " + j + " rolled as a combination of two dice is: " + arrayone[j]); 

        }

    }

}
```

My die code:

```
public class Die
{
    int roll()
    {
        double x = Math.random();
        x = 1.0 + (x * 6.0);
        int outcome = (int)Math.floor(x);

        return outcome;
    }    
}
```

I'm not really sure why I'm getting this error though I can see i'm being told it's the line `arrayone[dT]++;` which is causing the error.
Can somebody please point me in the right direction and correct me?

Comment: Can you share the code of `Die.roll()` please?

Comment: What's the range of `Die.roll()`? If it's more than seven, this is entirely possible.

Comment: public class Die
{
    int roll()
    {
        double x = Math.random();
        x = 1.0 + (x * 6.0);
        int outcome = (int)Math.floor(x);
            
        return outcome;
    }    
}

Comment: @Espore Add this snippet to the question please

Comment: The exception does not correspond to the code you present.  The only line the exception could refer to (based on the line number and exception class) is this: `arrayone[dT]++;`, but the exception specifies that the out-of-bounds index is 7, and `arrayone` is explicitly dimensioned with 14 elements.

Comment: @utrecht I've added the die code to the main question now

Comment: Now post you actual code. This one cant lead to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at index 7

Comment: can u add a comment to the line throwing the exception. We don't want to count lines.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know where to go from there then because there shouldn't be any other reason for the error. I can't see where it would go out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: @talex I've posted all of the actual code

Comment: I already told you: the error does not correspond to the code you presented.  It is therefore useless to study this code to try to determine the nature of the error.  You are running something else, probably compiled from a previous version of the source.  Recompile and try again.

Comment: Do you still getting error? Maybe you running old version. Try clean classfiles and rebuild.

Comment: I think it was a problem with the IDE Bluejay because since trying to run the code in eclipse it seems to work. I have no idea how this happened but thankyou for all the help guys.

Comment: as a side note: since the maximum result for 2 rolls is 12, why is he even defining a size 14 array? size 12 array with -1 offset or size 13 array would be just right here, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @vaxquis that was an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, I just ran it with a loop of 1000000.  The easiest solution is probably to just create a new project and copy the code into that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure you size `arrayone` to contain at least twice the max value that `Die.roll()` can return.

I ran the code you've provided so far and it generated the following:

```
The amount of 0 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 0
The amount of 1 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 0
The amount of 2 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 2
The amount of 3 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 1
The amount of 4 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 1
The amount of 5 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 0
The amount of 6 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 1
The amount of 7 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 2
The amount of 8 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 2
The amount of 9 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 0
The amount of 10 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 0
The amount of 11 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 1
The amount of 12 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 0
The amount of 13 rolled as a combination of two dice is: 0
```

Have you made other changes to the code?

Comment: I'm curious.  Why the downvote?  Both of my statements are correct, and both were appropriate given the amount of information the original post provided at the time.

Answer (score -1):

Surround your access to arrayone with try/catch:

```
try {
  arrayone[dT]++;
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  System.out.println("The value of d1 is " + d1);
  System.out.println("The value of d2 is " + d2);
}
```

Then you will see where an assumption you made is false.

Comment: Not my downvote (because the advice is fine), but this isn't helpful.  We already know from the exception message what the value of the out-of-bounds index is.

Answer (score -2):

Array size is 14 and you are trying to insert the value at the index is more than 13.

Comment: The exception message gives the out-of-bounds index as 7.  Last I checked, 7 is not more than 13.